# Change child theme after updating parent theme

Tags: child-theme

First of all, I apologize for my poor English

I use a theme for our site that needs a lot of changes.

I was told to use Child theme, So that the changes we have made will not be lost in the next update.
To make changes to the Child theme, for example, when I want to change the RTL file, I have to copy the RTL file from the main theme to the Child theme folder and make the changes to that file.
But my problem is that if in the next version of the theme changes are made in the original RTL file of the theme, then the contents of my RTL file that I copied in Child theme are old and those new changes are no longer applied and I have to bring the new RTL file and re-apply my changes again.

So what is the practical use of using a Child theme? Now, what is the difference between changing the RTL file directly or bringing it to the Child theme folder and then changing it?

Is it possible to load the CSS or PHP or even Java files I want to change into Child theme and then write only the code I want instead of copying the original file and that Edit?

Comment: You don't need to copy over the entire file, instead you can load your own scripts and stylesheets in the child that eventually override the ones from the parent.  And that way, you don't have to have child theme scripts and styles that cover EVERYTHING that the parent does, rather just the stuff that you want to change.
It could be as simple as a single line of CSS in your `rtl.css` file - because the parent is already loading it's own and then loading your version second, so your version will overrule the parent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable child theme, then from admin dashboard go to the preferences and click to customize then add CSS code there.

be sure to update the parent theme only.

there are always will be issues after each theme update, so u need to backup before the update, if the theme doesn't support RTL by default don't use it.